# jQuery $.ajax method being received but not being processed by Python

Tags: python, html, ajax, forms, cgi

I'm currently developing a webpage that will take in a user input of a list of items and send it to my Python script. The input is a list of items that is to be compared to an earlier version of itself for changes. The webpage consists of the following html:

```
<body>
<div id="header">
  <h1>Specialist Verification Report</h1>
</div>
<div id="report">
  <div>
    <form class="textbox">
      <textarea id="specialistreport" name="username" placeholder="Paste Report Here" required></textarea>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div>
    <form class="textbox">
      <textarea id="output" placeholder="Output" readonly></textarea>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <button id="send">SEND REPORT</button>
</div>
```

I am using the $.ajax method in JavaScript to process the input from the textbox:

```
   $('#send').click(function() {
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url:"SVR.py",
     data: {output: document.getElementById("specialistreport").value},
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(result) {
       document.getElementById("output").value = result;
     },
     error: function() {
       document.getElementById("output").value = "ERROR";
       console.log("ERROR");
     }
   });
 });
```

SVR.py:

```
    import cgi
    import cgitb
    import json
    import os

    #Special exception handler. Displays detailed reports in Web browser if errors occur.
    cgitb.enable()

    #Bunch of irrelevant functions in between

    #Initiate FieldStorage
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()

    if 'output' in form:
        print "Content-Type: text/json; charset=ISO-8859-1\n"
        print json.dumps("success")
    else:
        print "Content-Type: text/json; charset=ISO-8859-1\n"
        print json.dumps("error")
```

This is the result I get when I run the webpage:

```
    FieldStorage(None, None, ")
    <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: not indexable
            args = ('not indexable',)
            message='not indexable'
```

So jQuery runs the $.ajax success function every time it runs which tells me that it's finding the file fine, but python prints "error" and doesn't seem to be able to recognize the output key. Can somebody please help?